# Glass Models not populating

Tags: glass-mapper

We are int he process of upgrading out solution and found that some of our glass models are not populating. IPage implementations are not showing up values in the IGlassBase. Here are the sample models:

**IPage**

```cs
public interface IPage : IBasePage
{
    [SitecoreField]
    string Title { get; set; }
    [SitecoreField]
    string Body { get; set; }
}
```

**IGlassBase**

```cs
public interface IGlassBase
{
    Guid Id { get;  set; }

    Language Language { get;  set; }

    int Version { get;  set; }

    Guid BaseTemplateIds { get; set; }

    string TemplateName { get;  set; }

    Guid TemplateId { get; set; }

    string Name { get;  set; }

    string Url { get;  set; }
}
```

**GlassGlassBaseMap**

```cs
public class GlassGlassBaseMap : SitecoreGlassMap<IGlassBase>
{

    public override void Configure()
    {
        Map(x =>
        {
            x.AutoMap();
            x.Info(y => y.BaseTemplateIds).InfoType(SitecoreInfoType.BaseTemplateIds);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your `IBasePage` inherit from `IGlassBase`?

Comment: yes Corey it does inherit from IGlassBase

Comment: It looks like you are mixing fluent configuration with attribute configuration.  Do you register both configuration loaders?  Maybe posting your GlassMapperScCustom would help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't mix configuration methods in Glass Mapper. Your `IPage` model is using attribute configuration but your `IGlassBase` model is using fluent configuration. Remove the `SitecoreField` attributes from your `IPage` properties or add `SitecoreField` attributes to all of your `IGlassBase` properties and remove your fluent configuration map.

Comment: Did it the other way round by adding fluent to the IPage and it started working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the `[SitecoreType]` attribute.  Something like this:

```cs
[SitecoreType(TemplateId=MyTemplateIds.Page)]
public interface IPage : IBasePage
{
    [SitecoreField]
    string Title { get; set; }
    [SitecoreField]
    string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben but that is not helping. I tried to be specific with the interface and also the properties.

Answer (score 0):

ASURA - I think you need to make the properties on your model virtual.

This has tripped me up a few times before.

```cs
public interface IPage : IBasePage
{
    [SitecoreField]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    [SitecoreField]
    public virtual string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but specifying that does not help this problem. For my interfaces I do not specify public nor do I virtual.

Comment: Interfaces can't have virtual properties.

Comment: Ahr sorry, didn't notice it was an interface. So adding a template Id attribute isn't working either. Are you field names called exactly what you have as the property names?

Comment: Yeah, I usually use no spaces in my fields. That checks out as well.

Comment: Ok, as otherwise I was going to say we usually decorate our properties like so and set the field name as a constant:
[SitecoreField(FieldName = Fields.Title )]
string Title { get; set; }
If thats not the issue though that won't help.